# Why won't this Audio play in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, invalidoperationexception, soundeffect

I am trying to play audio in my Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 app. I have an MP3 audio file with its build action set to resource. To play the sound, I use:

```
SoundEffectInstance sfi = null;
...
        Stream source = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Bird Calls;component/Crow.mp3", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(source);
        sfi = effect.CreateInstance();
        sfi.Play();
```

This code throws a InvalidOperationException at the SoundEffect.FromStream method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SoundEffect  can't play mp3 file. If you want to play mp3 file, you should use MediaPlayer like that

```
private Song song;


string musicUrl = string.Format("/Bird Calls;component/Crow.mp3");
song = Song.FromUri("name", new Uri(musicUrl, UriKind.Relative));
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out myself. The solution to this problem is to use .wav files instead of .mp3's.

Comment: See Cong Tran's answer for an alternative